# Asp.Net Core WebAPI deployed to Azure is not issuing manually set Cookies, but works locally?

Tags: asp.net-core

In order to avoid storing the Jwt in the browser, I am storing the jwt inside of a cookie configured to be :

```
`
HttpOnly = true,
SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
IsEssential = true
`
```

I then run an interceptor as part of my request pipeline and check to see if the incoming request has a cookie with it if it does I then strip the cookie and add the `"Authorization"` header to the request with the contents of the cookie which is the jwt itself.

These cookie configurations work perfectly fine on my local machine in development. However once I deploy the app to Azure. The Web API is no longer issuing those cookies.

In my Asp.Net Core web api `Startup.cs` file I have the following, in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
`
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
      {
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied);
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ReplaceRedirector(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin);

        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
      });
`

`
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
      {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
      .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
      {
        configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
        configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        // In case of having an expired token
        configureOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
          OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
          {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
              context.Response.Headers.Add(TokenOptionsStrings.ExpiredToken, "true");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
          }
        };
      });
`
```

Then in my `Configure.cs` file:

```
`
app.UseMiddleware<JwtBearerMiddleware>()
          .UseCors("AllowAll")
          .UseAuthentication()
          .SeedDatabase()
          .UseHttpsRedirection()
          .UseMvc();
`
```

Then I finally issue the cookie upon successful sign up:

```
`
response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, token.access_token, _cookieOptions);
`
```

Where the `_cookieOptions` are the same as mentioned above.

Any idea why my cookie may not be getting issued when deployed to Azure?

Comment: To check whether it is related with your `JwtBearerMiddleware`, try code `Response.Cookies.Append("Test","TestValue", new CookieOptions() {  HttpOnly = true,  SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,  IsEssential = true  });` in Controller action, will it append the cookies?

Comment: I tried your exact code, and it is still not issuing the cookie. Hmm rather unforunate because I have no idea how else to even troubleshoot this. Maybe I can try disabling jwt middleware

Comment: Will it work if disable the jwt middleware?

Comment: no. So the cookie is sent I can see it in the Response headers `set-cookie: application_token="...` but the browser is not persisting the cookie!! AHhhh i have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Try to create a new default asp.net core project and add `Response.Cookies.Append("Test","TestValue", new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, IsEssential = true });`, will it work or not?

Comment: I figured it out.... It was Azure all along. I didnt have a checkbox checked on their CORS settings `Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. My code was right all along. However on the client side I needed to send the requests with the `{withCredentials: true}` object, this with the checkbox, issued the cookie and sent it back again with any subsequent request. 2 days later figured it out. Thank you for trying to help. I really appreciate it.